# How to avoid dropping static table when dropping temp table

Tags: sql, postgresql, temp-tables

In postgres, how I can avoid accidenial dropping static table when I try to drop temp table.
Query below would drop table **foo** on default schema if temp table **foo** wouldn't exist.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS foo;
CREATE TEMP TABLE foo AS
```

Comment: Prefix all temporary tables with something like `temp`.  The naming convention will ensure that you are working on the class of tables you want to affect.

Comment: `SET search_path to '';`

Comment: You're playing a dangerous game! Consider setting a prefix on the temp tables to avoid this confusion

Comment: @GordonLinoff Unless someone will creat static table with this prefix. Unfortunately, naming convention is not enough, I need something more precise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temp tables are implicitly created in the `pg_temp` schema. You can specify that schema when dropping the table:

```
drop table if exists pg_temp.foo;
create temp table foo;
```